# How to load and process multiple csv files from a DBFS directory with Spark

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, dataframe, databricks

I want to run the following code on each file that I read from DBFS (Databricks FileSystem). I tested it on all files that are in a folder, but I want to make similar calculations for each file in the folder, one by one:

```
// a-e are calculated fields
val df2=Seq(("total",a,b,c,d,e)).toDF("file","total","count1","count2","count3","count4")

//schema is now an empty dataframe
val final1 = schema.union(df2)
```

Is that possible? I guess reading it from dbfs should be done differently as well, from what I do now:

```
val df1 = spark
      .read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("delimiter",",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .load("dbfs:/Reports/*.csv")
      .select("lot of ids")
```

Thank you a lot in advance for the ideas :)

Comment: hi @Eva how many files like that do you have?

Comment: Actually you have two options here, either groupBy the file name and execute the logic for each file. Either iterate through your directory load the file into a Dataframe, execute the logic and then union with the other Dataframe

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis Thank you for your comments, I don't know how many files I have, it always changing, as this folder is updated every week with new data. I generated a function now, which I try to call on each files, I will share the code here tomorrow. And yea in the end I will try to union it... I have problems with the foreach and for syntaxes :D I'm on it :)

Comment: you welcome Eva :) good luck

Comment: hello Eva, please be aware that you can not change your initial question arbitrarily as your project evolves and you move on with your code. If everyone does that SO would be full of individual projects and not specific technical questions. My answer was over a specific question, now the question is different and not related to the first one so is better to create a new question with a new description as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed you have 3 options here.

In my example I am using the next 3 datasets:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|1   |100 |200 |
|2   |300 |400 |
+----+----+----+

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|3   |60  |80  |
|4   |12  |100 |
|5   |20  |10  |
+----+----+----+

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|7   |20  |40  |
|8   |30  |40  |
+----+----+----+
```

You create first you schema (is faster to define the schema explicitly instead of inferring it):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df_schema =
  StructType(
    List(
        StructField("col1", IntegerType, true),
        StructField("col2", IntegerType, true),
        StructField("col3", IntegerType, true)))
```

**Option 1:**

Load all CSVs at once with:

```
val df1 = spark
      .read
      .option("header", "false")
      .option("delimiter", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "false")
      .schema(df_schema)
      .csv("file:///C:/data/*.csv")
```

Then apply your logic to the whole dataset grouping by the file name.

***Precondition***: You must find a way to append the file name to each file

**Option 2:**

Load csv files from directory. Then iterate over the files and create a dataframe for each csv. Inside the loop apply your logic to each csv. Finally in the end of the loop append (union) the results into a 2nd dataframe which will store your accumulated results.

**Attention:** Please be aware that a large number of files might cause a very big DAG and subsequently a huge execution plan, in order to avoid this you can persist the current results or call collect. In the example below I assumed that persist or collect will get executed for every bufferSize iterations. You can adjust or even remove this logic according to the number of csv files.

This is a sample code for the **2nd option**:

```
import java.io.File
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import spark.implicits._

val dir = "C:\\data_csv\\"
val csvFiles = new File(dir).listFiles.filter(_.getName.endsWith(".csv"))

val bufferSize = 10
var indx = 0
//create an empty df which will hold the accumulated results
var bigDf = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], df_schema)
csvFiles.foreach{ path => 
    var tmp_df = spark
                  .read
                  .option("header", "false")
                  .option("delimiter", ",")
                  .option("inferSchema", "false")
                  .schema(df_schema)
                  .csv(path.getPath)

    //execute your custom logic/calculations with tmp_df

    if((indx + 1) % bufferSize == 0){
        // If buffer size reached then
        // 1. call unionDf.persist() or unionDf.collect()
        // 2. in the case you use collect() load results into unionDf again 
    }

    bigDf = bigDf.union(tmp_df)
    indx = indx + 1
}
bigDf.show(false)
```

This should output:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|1   |100 |200 |
|2   |300 |400 |
|3   |60  |80  |
|4   |12  |100 |
|5   |20  |10  |
|7   |20  |40  |
|8   |30  |40  |
+----+----+----+
```

**Option 3:**

The last option is to use the build-in `spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles`.

This is the code to load all csv files into a RDD:

```
val data = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("file:///C:/data_csv/*.csv")
val df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

df.show(false)
```

And the output:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|_1                        |_2                        |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|file:/C:/data_csv/csv1.csv|1,100,200                 |
|                          |2,300,400                 |
|file:/C:/data_csv/csv2.csv|3,60,80                   |
|                          |4,12,100                  |
|                          |5,20,10                   |
|file:/C:/data_csv/csv3.csv|7,20,40                   |
|                          |8,30,40                   |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

`spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles` will return a key/value RDD in which key is the file path and value is the file data.

This requires extra code to extract the content of the _2 which is the content of each csv. In my opinion this would consist an overhead regarding the performance and the maintainability of the program therefore I would have avoided it.

Let me know if you need further clarifications

Comment: In the end I made a function that I call on each files, and the results I write out as appended csv. Thank you a lot for your effort!! :)

Comment: Hi Eva, great I am happy that it helped you!

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis . For the second option that you suggested. You told that for large number of files to break the huge execution plan, we can call persist() or collect(). If I call persist() then it should be the default optionof memory only or it should be disk only. I have around 2500 files and similar scenario.

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya by default cache or persist will save the data with MEMORY_AND_DISK. Please check the next for further details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520428/what-is-the-difference-between-memory-only-and-memory-and-disk-caching-level-in

Answer (score 2):

I am adding to the answer that @Alexandros Biratsis provided.
One can use the First Approach as below by concatenating the file name as a separate column within the same dataframe that has all the data from multiple files.

```
val df1 = spark  
      .read  
      .option("header", "false")  
      .option("delimiter", ",")  
      .option("inferSchema", "false")  
      .schema(df_schema)  
      .csv("file:///C:/data/*.csv")  
      .withColumn("FileName",input_file_name())
```

Here `input_file_name()` is a function that adds the name of the file to each row within the `DataFrame`. This is an inbuilt function in spark.
To use this function you need to import the below namespace.
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

One can find the documentation for the function at https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html

I would advise not to use the second approach suggested by @Alexandros Biratsis of doing union and persisting the temporary dataframes as it would work for small number of files but as the number of files gets increased it becomes too slow and sometimes it gets timed out and driver gets shutdown unexpectedly.

I would like to thank Alexandros for answer as that gave me a way to move forward with the problem.